# RegisterEventHotKey from thread

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I followed this awesome tutorial to set up a hotkey - http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/

However I am doing this from a thread. So I suspect I need to run some kind of event loop. I have tried:

- `WaitNextEvent` - with the `everyEvent` argument set to `0` - I guessed on that one because I can't figure out where they define it here - https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/dispatch_aes_aepg/dispatch_aes_aepg.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001449-CH204

  ```
  gotEvent = WaitNextEvent(everyEvent, &event, 32767L, cursorRgn);
  ```
- `RunCurrentEventLoop` - https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/RunCurrentEventLoop
- `CFRunLoopRun` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRun
- `CFRunLoopInMode` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRunInMode

But I can't seem to get the hotkey to work. This is my code:

```
//Register the Hotkeys
EventHotKeyRef gMyHotKeyRef;

EventHotKeyID gMyHotKeyID;
gMyHotKeyID.signature='htk1';
gMyHotKeyID.id=1;

EventTypeSpec eventType;
eventType.eventClass=kEventClassKeyboard;
eventType.eventKind=kEventHotKeyPressed;

InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,NULL,NULL);

RegisterEventHotKey(49, shiftKey, gMyHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &gMyHotKeyRef);
```

Can you please advise.

I also tried `InstallEventHandler` with `GetEventDispatcherTarget` instead of `GetEventApplicationTarget`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any kind of GUI event loop running — Carbon or Cocoa?  It'd make more sense to just use that instead than to try to run your own event loop.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasRiley for the comment. I don't have any other loop. I am making a plugin for another app, and it has to be in another thread.

Comment: Have you checked the return values from `InstallApplicationEventHandler()` and `RegisterEventHotKey()`? Have you tried a hot key combination besides Shift-space, which might not be allowed? For example, try Command-Shift-space. In any case, this stuff may not work from a background thread. Certainly, even if registering the handler and the hot key work, I would expect the handler to be called from the main thread's event loop, since that's the only thread which receives events.

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases, the result of `InstallEventHandler` with `GetEventDispatcherTarget` was `0` and that of `RegisterEventHotKey` was `4294967246`. I thought this would work because I was able to get `CGEventTap` to work from a thread as here - https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl/blob/master/modules/workers/MMSyncWorker.js#L1002-L1232 - I'm trying the cmd + shift right now :)

Comment: Event taps work differently. They don't depend on the app event loop. By the way, 4294967246 is actually -50, `paramErr`. Since you're not actually using C code such as you show in your question, you should double-check your translation from JavaScript.

Comment: Ah thanks so much @KenThomases I'll check more :) Really appreciate your attention! :)

Comment: Hey @KenThomases I was wondering if you would be able to chat via stackoverflow if we can go over the types of my code toagther. So sorry I know I bother you so much. :( I think it's some type or something I'm unknowningly messing up. For `kEventClassKeyboard` I am using `0x6B657962` and for `kEventHotKeyPressed` I am using `5` is this correct? I have moved my code to the main thread, was still getting this param err :(

Comment: Oh this is my mainthread attempt - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/hotkey-nix-mac-on-mainthread-exp/bootstrap.js#L4217-L4251 and the types are here - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/hotkey-nix-mac-on-mainthread-exp/modules/ostypes_mac.jsm - forgive this bother please

Comment: Why are you using `GetEventMonitorTarget()`? You should be using `GetApplicationEventTarget()` for both the call to `InstallEventHandler()` and `RegisterEventHotKey()`. Note in the docs for [`GetEventMonitorTarget()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetEventMonitorTarget) how restricted in purpose and function it is.

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases I tried that at first but it was giving me this so I started experimenting. I made that change and updated the commit though. Verifying its still giving -50 :(. This guy here recommened using `GetDispatcherEventTarget` I tried that too but it failed :( - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2929889/1828637

Comment: You can try passing in a different key code, such as 0, which corresponds to the leftmost letter key in the middle row of letters (the 'A' key on a U.S. ANSI keyboard). By the way, I forgot to confirm: yes, `0x6B657962` is correct for `kEventClassKeyboard`, and `5` is correct for `kEventHotKeyPressed`. Something to check: are you sure this ctypes thing, or whatever it is, properly handles passing a structure as a function parameter by value and not pointer? This is how `gMyHotKeyID` has to be passed to `RegisterEventHotKey()`.

Comment: By the way, I notice that your definition of `RunCurrentEventLoop` has a copy-paste error. It uses `UnregisterEventHotKey` in its `declare()` call.

Comment: Thanks for that copy paste error haha I'll fix. I'm pretty sure i have never had a problem passing structure as func param. I'll ask an expert right now and share with you :)

Comment: @KenThomases I asked and they said yes it supports passing struct by value. I'm looking in my old codes to see if I ever did this, I'm pretty sure I have.

Comment: Hey @KenThomases is possible that `InstallEventHandler` set up something wrong even though its return is `0`?

Comment: Oh my gosh my friend got it working in a scratchpad scope! https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8867126 Thanks so much for all your help Im going to compare my thing to my friends thing! Oh my gosh thanks for your attention even though mistake was mine somewhere!

Comment: Wowwww @KenThomases you know the problem? I was using `UInt32 = ctypes.unsigned_long` but `ctypes.unsigned_long` is 64bit so I had to switch to `UInt32 = ctypes.uint32_t` ouch!!! haha

Comment: Woohoo @KenThomases got it done! Submitted to the market - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - please check it out, its all thanks to you! :) I tried to get it to work from a thread but I could not :( Had to do from main thread.